# What am I doing wrong when calling return self.property in a django model?

Tags: python, django

Model

```
from django.db import models

class Domain(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    expires = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.url
```

Shell

```
>>>Domian.objects.all()
[<Domain: Domian object>]
```

It should be

```
[<Domain: http://voikai.com>]
```

What is causing this error?

Comment: Have you reloaded the shell since you added the unicode method?

Comment: I don't know whether this is significant but your class is called `Domain` but in your example you spelt it `Domian`.  Maybe you aren't testing what you think you are testing?

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure, but try to return an actual unicode string in `__unicode__` method.

As in

```
return u"%s" %(self.url,)
```

Comment: @okm: Not just your opinion, there. It *is* unicode. All model attributes in Django are always unicode.